# Early-breaking from Rust's match

Tags: pattern-matching, rust, match, break

I want to switch through many possible cases for `x` and there's one case (here `x == 0`) where I want to check the result of some additional code to determine what to do next. One possibility is to return early from the match.

I'd use `break` to do this early-returning in C, but this isn't allowed in Rust. `return` returns from the parent function (in this case `main()`) and not from the match only (i.e. the `println!` at the end isn't run!).

I could just negate the sub-condition (here `y == 0`) and indent the whole lot of following code -- but I find this ugly and unreadable.

Putting the sub-condition into a match-guard is no option for me since it's simply too big.

Is this possible in Rust or is there a better alternative (except creating another subfunction or other work-arounds)?

Minimal example:

```
fn main() {
    let x = 1;

    match x {
        1 => {
            let y = 0;
            /*
             * do ev1l stuff to y that I don't want to put into the match-guard
             * as it's simply too much.
             */

            /* break early ... */
            if y == 0 {break;} // > error: `break` outside of loop [E0268]

            assert!(y != 0, "y was 0!");
            /* do other stuff in here. */
        }
        _ => {}
    }

    println!("done matching");
}
```

I found [Mixing matching, mutation, and moves in Rust](http://blog.rust-lang.org/2015/04/17/Enums-match-mutation-and-moves.html) — is it wrong?

> `match` embraces both imperative and functional styles of programming: you can continue using `break` statements, assignments, et cetera, rather than being forced to adopt an expression-oriented mindset.

Comment: My thought process while reading the question: *Create an `else` block. Oh, OP disallowed that. Maybe a match guard? Oh, OP disallowed that. Make a function? Oh, OP disallowed that*.

Comment: My question is specifically whether there's such an equivalent to `break` since imho it's the most "clean" way to solve this problem. Ofcourse if it's not possible I will refrain to one of the other options but imho these are "overkill" for what I want to do.

Comment: There's no way to do this under your restrictions.

Comment: *these are "overkill" for what I want to do.* I don't think so, using functions to simplify match guards is a great way to make code more readable (a helpful name for the function being a prerequisite of course). Remember, other people need to read your code after you write it. Other people include future you that forgot what's going on here.

Comment: @ker The code is really simple and straight-forward but long. That's why it's imho neither appropriate for a function (it's more readable if it's just sitting there, there's no re-use either) nor for putting it into a match-guard since it's too long.  But this is not about code-style but just about it being possible or not. So if WiSaGaN is right I'd accept this as an answer (if he'd make it one)

Comment: @larkey: shortening a long but simple piece of code into a (local) function (maybe even a function-local-function) is definitely a way to increase readability. Using a closure can even get you around the issue of too many arguments

Comment: @ker That's your opinion but not to debate here ;)

Comment: *That's your opinion* true. *but not to debate here* one should always strife to consider other opinions :)

Comment: @key I did so but I just don't want to discuss it any further in *this* question (possibly on code-review or similar) ;)

Comment: @larkey the blog post you've linked is interesting, but I honestly don't know what it means with that sentence.

Comment: @Shepmaster Yep, especially considering it's rather 'official' and recent.

Comment: @larkey "recent" is dubious. It's over a year old, but more importantly it [predates Rust 1.0](http://blog.rust-lang.org/2015/05/15/Rust-1.0.html).

Comment: @Shepmaster Sure but I think 1yr is still *rather* recent -- at least one of the more up-to-date resources.

Comment: @larkey **predating Rust 1.0** is the important part. 1.0 set the mold for Rust; lots of things before 1.0 no longer make sense.

Answer (score 14):

This has changed at some point, now you can use labels to break out of any block!

e.g.

```rust
fn main() {
    let x = 1;

    match x {
        1 => 'label: {
            let y = 0;

            /* break early ... */
            if y == 0 {
                break 'label;
            }

            assert!(y != 0, "y was 0!");
            /* do other stuff in here. */
        }
        _ => {}
    }

    println!("done matching");
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Something else you could do is make a "self-executing" closure and use a return statement inside. I don't know whether there are any weird performance characteristics of this but syntactically it's pretty clean.

```
fn main() {
    let x = 1;

    // This closure is just used to catch the "return" statement.
    (|| {
        match x {
            1 => {
                let y = 0;
                /*
                 * do ev1l stuff to y that I don't want to put into the match-guard
                 * as it's simply too much.
                 */

                /* break early ... */
                if y == 0 { return; } // Ok!

                assert!(y != 0, "y was 0!");
                /* do other stuff in here. */
            }
            _ => {}
        }
    })();

    println!("done matching");
}
```

Here's a [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2e0c7ee456da811961f3c8af00c4a81c&version=stable) showing it working.

Comment: *any weird performance characteristics* — there should not be as I expect this to be covered by Rust's "zero-cost abstractions".

Comment: Great idea, it reminds me of those javascript self-executing closure tricks to isolate parts of the code !

Answer (score 8):

You can wrap the `match` into a `loop` that only runs once and break out of the loop

```
fn main() {
    let x = 1;

    loop { match x {
        1 => {
            let y = 0;
            /*
             * do ev1l stuff to y that I don't want to put into the match-guard
             * as it's simply too much.
             */

            /* break early ... */
            if y == 0 { break; }

            assert!(y != 0, "y was 0!");
            /* do other stuff in here. */
        }
        _ => {}
    } break; }

    println!("done matching");
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach but I think rather obfuscates the idea more than it should and is not exactly an answer to my question. Have an upvote but I cannot accept it ;)

Comment: why doesn't it answer your question? it lets you break out of the match right? im asking because im porting a big C 1000+ line switch statement and this is pretty much how im dealing with breaking out of the middle of a match

Comment: @donbright This solution _works_, but I think it's misleading code. If I came across it in the wild, I would have first assumed that the match is executed multiple times, when this is not the case. It would take me quite a while to figure this out, after which I would almost definitely try to refactor the `loop` statement out - assuming it to be a relic left by a previous fix.

Comment: i get it now, thank you Camp bell. if i wasnt porting C i would never use this trick... i'd just rewrite it to make more sense in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

You could create a macro like

```
macro_rules! block {
    ($xs:block) => {
        loop { break $xs }
    };
}
```

and do

```
match x {
    1 => block!({
        ...
        if y == 0 { break; }
        ...
    })
    _ => {}
}
```

It's not an amazing solution, but it is semantically meaningful.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: you can't.

The fact that you are trying to do this is a sign that you are not writing idiomatic Rust.

If you absolutely need to break out of a match, consider putting your match in a function that returns a value... this way you can have good control over borrowing, compared to a simple block of code. Then pass the variable to match to the function that will match inside of it. i.e.

```
fn match_it(val: i8) -> i8 {
    let mut a: i8 = 0;
    match random_or(0, 1) {
        1 => {
                a = 5;
                // other ev1l stuff
                if a == 6 { return 1 }
             },
        0 => a = -5,
        _ => (),
    };
    
    a //return a
}
```

Based on your code, though, you could just flip two statements and you would achieve your desired control flow:

```
        if y == 0 {break;} // > error: `break` outside of loop [E0268]

        assert!(y != 0, "y was 0!");
        /* do other stuff in here. */
```

turns into:

```
        if y != 0 {
             assert!(y != 0, "y was 0!");
             /* do other stuff in here. */
        }

        // if we reach here, by definition one of these conditions is true: y == 0, or y != 0 and code above has run and completed.
```