# How to return a value from a match expression without returning in the function?

Tags: rust

So I'm new to Rust so this may be something really trivial to fix. I've been following the programming book that comes with my rust installation, it's been going pretty good so far. I'm on chapter 8.3 and at the end the first exercise is to implement a function that will get the median and mode of a list of values. The functions that calculates the mode is not working correctly.

This is my current implementation:

```rust
fn get_mode_of(number_count: &mut HashMap<i32, u32>) -> Option<(i32, u32)> {
    let mut current_mode: Option<(i32, u32)> = None;
    for (number, count) in number_count {
        println!("Comparing: ({}, {})", number, count);
        current_mode = match current_mode {
            None => Some((*number, *count)),
            Some(mode) => {
                if let Ordering::Less = mode.1.cmp(&count) {
                    println!("Comparing value: {} and {}", mode.1, count);
                    return Some((*number,*count));
                }
                println!("Comparing value: {} and {}", mode.1, count);
                return Some(mode);
            }
        };
        println!("Current mode is None: {}", {current_mode.is_none()});
    }
    return current_mode;
}
```

The problem is, the program doesn't runs the for loop more than two times. I suspect this is because of the returns inside the loop, which I think Rust thinks is a return of the functions instead of a return to assign a value to current_mode.

How could I rewrite the code below to actually assign a value to current_mode instead of just returning?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Early-breaking from Rust's match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814942/early-breaking-from-rusts-match)

Comment: Thanks! It does help a little but the question is asking for breaking a loop, I'm asking how to make the match return a value instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct, you can only return from functions as opposed to control flow constructs like loops and match statements. So it will always return from the entire function without continuing.

If you wish to take advantage of early returns, you could split the function into two with a helper for the `Some(mode)` case and call it in the main `get_mode_of` function.

However, in this case you should be able to take advantage of Rust's block expressions evaluating to their last part or operand (resource: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/block-expr.html) like so:

```
Some(mode) => {
    println!("Comparing value: {} and {}", mode.1, count);
    if let Ordering::Less = mode.1.cmp(&count) {
        Some((*number,*count))
    } else {
        Some(mode)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, this is a bit of an XY problem since the standard library has [`Iterator::max_by()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.max_by), which lets you reduce a sequence of values to the maximal one by a custom comparison function.  Writing out this logic in your code is therefore redundant with the standard library; just use the Iterator utility instead.

You also don't need to take the map by mutable reference since you don't change it.  An immutable reference will do.

For example:

```
fn get_mode_of(number_count: &HashMap<i32, u32>) -> Option<(i32, u32)> {
    number_count.iter()
        .max_by(|a, b| a.1.cmp(b.1))
        // Here we have Option<(&i32, &u32)>, map that to Option<(i32, u32)>
        .map(|(&a, &b)| (a, b))
}
```

Comment: I haven't really reached this part of the book yet. I still have to get acostumed to the syntax. I come from a C# background, is this something like LINQ and would this make my code slower/less performant in exchange for readability or would this have an almost 0 effect on performance?

Comment: Iterator methods are usually zero-cost, unless you explicitly use dynamic dispatch via `dyn Trait` somewhere. In some cases, they can even optimize better then the direct implementation, if the adapter manages to e.g. eliminate unnecessary bounds checking.